# Why is the behavior in the manual not consistent with the NebulaGraph Database

Tags: nebula-graph

Its behavior changes from time to time. Is the manual always consistent with Nebula Graph Database?

Answer (score 0):

NebulaGraph is still under development. Its behavior changes from time to time. Users can submit an issue to inform the team if the manual and the system are not consistent.

Comment: And such case is a good opportunity to Github PR to the docs project, too!